# C++ comments for functions in Qt creator

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, doxygen

How can I comment C++ functions in Qt creator so that when I hover over a function call to that function I may see the documentation as a tool tip.

Just like we do /** newline Eclipse create a comment block automatically I am looking for the same in Qt creator, please advise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are probably looking for something like [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/).

[Here are instructions](https://facwiki.cs.byu.edu/HCMI/index.php/Using_doxygen_with_Qt_Creator) for using it with Qt Creator.

Comment: I don't want to create html documentation pages, I just want to comment the functions and be able to see their the tooltips in the same project wherever I call it.. Just like if I type /// in visual studio it creates a summary element, similarly in eclipse we do /** to do the same

Comment: I was also really disappointed that this feature doesn't work out of the box. As for the need of the HTML files - contrary to Java, C++ has many docs frameworks, and the IDE cannot know which one you're using. It also cannot have install dependencies on all available docs generators. So this is at least the difference I see between Java and C++ dosctring processing.

Comment: The link is dead, can you update it and preferably add a small summery to your answer?